# API usage example for org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to perform analysis of a AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of a Java Source Code. I am able to generate the AST from a source file but not able to find API usage example of how to print the complete AST and how to iterate over various nodes of the AST.

```
String fileContent = ASTParserDemo1.readFileToString("file path");
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(fileContent.toCharArray());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
AST ast = cu.getAST();
```

How do I print the ast (I want to perform pattern matching and analyze the ast)

Comment: Does `toString()` print the typical unhelpful `className + "@" + hexDigits"?

Comment: This is what toString() printed: org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST@2f7300c2

Comment: Yep, that's not the helpful `toString()`...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/)?

Comment: Yes, ASTView is an Eclipse Plug-in which I installed and I am able to see the AST of a Java source file in Eclipse. However, my requirement is to programmatically analyze the AST. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, wouldn't a way to traverse the AST be more helpful than just printing it?

Answer (score 0):

To print a complete source code of a file use `toString()` method of a `CompilationUnit` class.

If you want to directly explore tree from the root start from [CompilationUnit](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/CompilationUnit.html).

However it is not very convenient and better is to use visitor [ASTVisitor](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html).